# Detecting .Net framework Reboot required

Tags: installation, nsis

My NSIS installer installs .Net framework 4.0 silently along with my application packages. Platform is Win Xp / 7 / 8.

```
ExecWait '"$TEMP\app-temp\dotNetFx40.exe" /q /norestart'
```

Now the thing is, if the dotNetFx40 installer returns a reboot required with 3010 code, windows should be rebooted before continuing. I cannot skip this as my application is dependent on .Net framework and moreover some dll needs to be registered during installation with presense of .Net.

To solve this, I can show a messagebox(YES_NO) and ask for reboot(triggering NSIS Reboot command on messagebox IDYES) and installation can be continued after next startup by registry RunOnce method.

Now, this should be done only if the .Net installer reports a 3010 error, which might be the case for few systems but not every system.

I can see that, event viewer logs this with reference of RestartManager but I think reading the event viewer is not possible with NSIS. So is there any other way to read this return code of .Net installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecWait` will tell you the exit code of the child process:

```
ExecWait '"c:\path\app.exe" /whatever' $0
DetailPrint $0
```

Comment: Great. Thats what I was looking for.